# Google maps v3 - World overview thumbnail?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way I can implement a feature to have a world overview thumbnail when browsing a google map?

What I am trying to describe is an indicator rectangle, with a full world map and a square region of where I am browsing in the world.

Sorry if this is vague, but I can't seem to find the right words to describe what I am looking for.

Will delete this post if it proves of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words you are looking for are "Overview Map":

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+Overview+map